SecIdentityCreateWithCertificate error on SecIdentity type
I have this part of the code in Swift on MacOS:
let mockPubKey = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAqKzXy2z1n6zX4OQ+5v2c\nCwIDAQAB\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"
let mockCertificate = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAqKzXy2z1n6zX4OQ+5v2c\nCwIDAQAB\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----"
let mockCertificateData = Data(base64Encoded: mockCertificate)
let pubKeyData = Data(base64Encoded: mockPubKey)
var error: Unmanaged<CFError>?
let certifcateData: SecCertificate = SecCertificateCreateWithData(nil, mockCertificateData! as CFData)!
var identity: SecIdentity?
let status = SecIdentityCreateWithCertificate(nil, certifcateData, &identity)
let mockPrivateKey = SecKeyCreateWithData(pubKeyData! as CFData, [:] as CFDictionary, &error)

And I am getting an error: Cannot convert value of type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<(any SecIdentity)?>' to expected argument type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<SecIdentity?>'
I found in multiple sources that this passing of identity is valid but for me it seems to not work.
Just FYI i use this code to mock some behaviour in test and found this part challenging as well when it comes to SecurityFramework mock. Maybe someone knows good resource of how to mock it effectively>

Strange. I have copied your exact code into an Xcode project and it compiled without errors or warnings.
